# Hoping to get fusion tables encrypted ID from a pre-existing javascript map that uses numeric ID

Tags: javascript, mapping, google-fusion-tables

While this may look like a duplicate of the standard old "how do I find the numeric ID" chestnut, I want to make it immediately clear that this is the **reverse** of that situation.

We have a numeric ID in hand for our legacy javascript mapping app (passed to us, of course, by another developer who is now out of the picture), and I am trying to get the encrypted ID from that app.

Is there any relatively simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the FusionTable with the following URL:

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?dsrcid=NumericId

Go to File > "About this table", that will tell you the encrypted ID.